# How to extend usb cable 30m thru ethernet? (with non-powered ethernet usb hub)

Tags: usb, power-supply, ethernet, hub, wireless-extender

I need to connect a usb hub 15m from my computer, i've tried a hub with 4 slots and a power supply, and a 15m active usb cable. The hub has a wireless Xbox receptor (with up to 4 xbox controllers simultaneously), a wireless keyboard, a mouse, and sometimes another wireless keyboard and mouse (in a single slot).

That setup doesn't work. Even with the powered usb hub, I can use max one keyboard and mouse simultaneously, but thats it. If I add one more all of them stop working.

I made some research and found the best solution is to use a ethernet extender for those distances, and I happen to have already a spare 30m ethernet cable.

However all great solutions with a powered ethernet usb hub are meant for business and thus are way than I need.

So my question is if a non-powered ethernet hub would be enough to work with all the devices mentioned above simultaneously. And if not, what if I attach the 4 slot powered hub to it?

```
devices -> 4 slot powered hub -> (female)usbToEthernet -> 30m ethernet cable -> ethernetToUsb(male) -> computer
```

Would that work? I made a lot of research, many people says you can't use high power demanding devices like a webcam or a external drive with non-powered setup, but I can't find information on how to evaluate if 4 xbox controllers + 2 keyboards + 2 mouses need too much speed/power or not.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"]([What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?](//meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/205)" class="soup-https-fixed).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Tera-Grand-Extender-Adapter-USB-VE399-P/dp/B00QPP61D4

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic. I've edited the question and removed the shopping allusions. Wasn't even my intention in the first place, my real question is actually more about power usage of low demading devices combined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if those devices would pull too much power, but you could simply use a powered usb hub, at the end with these devices - after all you're going to need to connect a hub anyway, why not use a powered one?

This way, the hub *will/should* provide the power and mean that you don't exceed what should be pulled over cat5e cable.